# Pause section and scroll inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm working on a client site and i'm currently having an issue firguring out how to make something work. the goal is to pause at the section and continue to scroll inside the iphone then continue to scroll once the iphone has finished scrolling. I have attempted to use position fixed on the section but obviously the body continues to scroll so I'm not sure if this is the right solution. I was wondering if this is something Skrollr could assist with as well. Does anyone have any ideas?

I've added a fiddle of the layout: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lm6he4j/1/

Psuedo HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="iphone_wrap">
        <div class="iphone_inner">
            <!--Message content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
   position:relative;
   min-height:500px;
   width:100%;
}

.iphone_wrap {
    width:400px;
    height:650px;
    position:absolute;
    left:20%;
    top:-200px;
    background:url('iphone.jpg');
}

.iphone_inner {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: I hate overflow scroll when I'm using a mobile device.  I get "stuck" in the inner scroll, it's especially bad if the height of the inner scroll section is taller than the screen, you really get trapped in it.  Why would you purposefully do that for a phone?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle of the problem? this can be done by preventing the browser's scroll defaullt behavior on mouse-over until the section's scroll as reached the bottom, then re-enabling it

Comment: @RightClick This will only be for the desktop version of the site, on mobile the iphone container will dissapear and the content will flow normally without any fixed positioning.

Comment: @loli here's a fiddle of the layout https://jsfiddle.net/9Lm6he4j/1/

Comment: your jsfiddle works for me, what browser you using?

Comment: @loli you can scroll inside the iphone but the thing i'm trying to accomplish is pause this section as you scroll down and scroll inside the iphone as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

one way you can do this is

- use javascript/jquery and set position fixed of the "blue color
  section" and "iphone wrapper"

  content which run inside the phone implement as a part of the
  underlying body of the page

  so the blue section + iphone wrapper will work as a overlay while the
  content of the iphone scroll below this section

  and using js/jquery you can reset the position fixed to relative
  after the end of that content.

Comment: This is a run-on sentence.  Can you edit your answer to be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) that might help you. It has really detailed doc's and well support by author on https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic