# Move large image inside smaller visible container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do something basic (beginner in programming).
I try to take a **large image and a smaller container**, and move the image `up` or `down` inside while the user scrolls.

So you can [image: click here].

Move the **yellow** `up` or `down` while the user can see the **red** in the same position (kept in doc flow).

If i create an image using this :

```
<div class="cvrContainer top left">
    <div class="cvrPhoto" id="photo0" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/900/850);"></div>
</div>
```

1. Should i set `cvrPhoto` to be larger then `cvrContainer` say 200% ?
2. How do i move it up/down with `JS` while keeping overflow hidden.

**I do not ask how to calculate,** only how to set it and move the only yellow inside

Comment: Can you please add the css snippet as well?

Comment: If the red `div` doesn't need to ever move, consider `position: fixed;` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, otherwise you're looking at needing some Javascript.

Comment: @Vector as i said, it happens during scrolling, so fixed is not good, and as I wrote, i do want to use javascript, no problem.

Comment: Check out this post then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939429/pause-section-and-scroll-inside-a-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using css for the inner image (not background image but `img` tag) :

```
.prlxPhoto
{

     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);

}
```

and move it left/right for example with :

```
var e = document.getElementById("1");
e.style.marginLeft = equotion+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create simple parallax effect, you can achieve this effect by position fixed, add `position: fixed` on `.cvrPhoto` div.

```css
.cvrContainer {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/900/850);
}

.cvrPhoto {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 57px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="cvrContainer style=" background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/900/850); "">
  <div class="cvrPhoto"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but did you read the question? a fixed position will put the image OUTSIDE of the flow. This code is not working obviously.